# How do I create a variable "DayOfWeek" without missing a day when plotting?

Tags: r, time

I have created an algorithm to create the variable `DayOfWeek` (Monday, Tuesday, etc). When I plot it, it always misses a day somehow. Also, when plotting, the days are not in normal order (It shows: Tuesday, Friday, Sunday,etc). The variable `InvoiceDate` is like `12/1/10 8:26`. How could I fix these issues?

```
data$DayOfWeek <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"
                , "Saturday","Friday")[as.POSIXlt(as.Date(data$InvoiceDate,"%d/%m/%Y"))$wday + 1]
```

Sales time series per day

```
timeseriesperday <- split(data$DayOfWeek, data$InvoiceNo)  # Convert data in the list
timeseriesperday <- as(timeseriesperday,"transactions") # Convert dates to transcriptions
itemFrequencyPlot(timeseriesperday,type="absolute", main="Sales time series per day",
              xlab="Day of the Week", ylab="Amount of Sales")
```

Comment: Use lowercase y for year and add 1 to the wday value since is 0-based

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But still they are not in order when I Plot "itemFrequencyPlot".

<timeseriespercountry <- split(data$Country, data$InvoiceNo)  # Convert data in the list
timeseriespercountry <- as(timeseriespercountry,"transactions") # Convert dates to transcriptions
itemFrequencyPlot(timeseriespercountry,type="absolute", main="Sales time series per Country",
                  xlab="Country", ylab="Amount of Sales")http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting>

Comment: @42 - Sorry I am new here and not sure how to paste code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to convert `DayOfWeek` to `factor` with levels in the required order?

```
listOfWeekdays <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                    "Friday", "Saturday")
data$DayOfWeek <- listOfWeekdays[as.POSIXlt(as.Date(data$InvoiceDate,"%d/%m/%y"))$wday + 1]
data$DayOfWeek <- factor(data$DayOfWeek, levels = listOfWeekdays)
```

As pointed out by @42- the format string needs to use lower case `%y` for 2 digits years (e.g. `10`) while upper case `%Y` expects 4 digits years (e.g. `2010`).

Comment: @42- Thank you. Copied from OP without further testing. Answer is fixed now.

Comment: I had converted to factor too (data$DayOfWeek <- as.factor(data$DayOfWeek)).

But even when I do "head(data$DayOfWeek)" after making it a factor, it is missing a day.

Comment: @42 - Sorry I am new here and not sure how to paste code.

Answer (score 1):

You needn't create the list of weekdays yourself. I'd recommend checking out the [lubridate package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/), with which you can call the function `wday()` on a timestamp to return the day.

If an example invoicedate was a Monday, `wday(invoicedate)` would return `2`, and `wday(invoicedate, label = TRUE` would return `Mon` (since the week begins on Sunday in this package: `Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat`

Comment: As `InvoiceDate` is character with an amigious date format (2 digits year as shown in the Q) be careful when calling `lubridate::wday` directly. Better convert explicitely using `lubridate::dmy_hm()` (note: the sample string `12/1/10 8:26` includes time components which requires `dmy_hm` instead of `dmy`).